# Using -snowfall- (or other packages) to parallel repeating a user-defined function

Tags: r, parallel-processing, snowfall

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490182/repeating-a-user-defined-function-using-replicate-or-sapply), where I was asking how to replicate a user-defined function. Now I would like to parallelize the operations in order to save time. What I have preliminarly done is:

1. I have defined a custom function `my.fun()`, which returns `output`, a matrix with `1000` rows and `20` columns.
2. I replicate say `5` times `output`, and store the results in a single matrix called `final` through: `final <- do.call(rbind, replicate(5, my.fun(), simplify=FALSE))`. Hence, in this example `final` is a `5000`-rows matrix.

What I would like to do now is to parallelize the 5 (or even more..) `output` replications before binding the results in the `final` matrix.

How would you do that? What I have (wrongly) done so far is:

```
    library(snowfall)

    sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 4, type = "SOCK")

    # previously defined objects manipulated within my.fun
    sfExport(...)

    my.fun = function() {
       ...
       return(output)
    }

    final <- do.call(rbind, sfSapply(1:5, fun=my.fun(), simplify=FALSE))

    sfStop()
```

but it returns:

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'fun' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please, consider that I do not necessairly want to use `-snowfall-`: the final goal is to parallelize the computation of `final` in an efficient way (in reality I have to make a lot of replications..).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sfSapply` expects `fun` to be a function, but you hand over the *result* of one call to `my.fun`. That is, you want to hand over `my.fun`, not `my.fun ()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with parallel computing in R.
I had to add a dummy argument to the function my.func, otherwise `sfSapply` complains with this error

```
 first error: unused argument(s) (X[[1]])
```

So I add x as argument

```
  my.fun <- function(x) matrix(1:4, 2,2)
```

Now I tried to benchmark the parallel and the `sapply` solution

```
  sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 4)
  library(rbenchmark)
  benchmark(
  pp = sfSapply(1:20000, fun=my.fun, simplify=FALSE),
  nopp = sapply(1:20000, FUN=my.fun, simplify=FALSE))
```

The parallel solution is slower than the classic one!! I am really confusing. maybe others more experienced with R paraelle computing can give us a logic explanation..

```
 test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2 nopp          100   15.22    1.000     13.90     0.02         NA        NA
1   pp          100   27.28    1.792     11.95     2.04         NA        NA
```

Comment: Parallelization always incurs some overhead. Only if the typical job executed in parallel takes a significant amount of time, say at least a few seconds, does parallel processing really provide an advantage. If the typical job takes milliseconds, then constantly launching jobs will incur so much overhead that the total processing time increases. Just add a few seconds of sleep to myfun to see the difference.

Comment: @agstudy the same error for me, I had to add the x argument too, thanks!